# ASP MVC Bundling and Minification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am comparing result between the project with/without bundling and minification implemented and trying to justify if the bundling and minification is actually adding some value.

I am bundling 10 js files, 7 css files. 
Here is the result i found:

Server result with bundling and minification enabled:
[image: Server Chrome Network Result]

Local result without bundling and minification enabled:
[image: Local Chrome Network Result]

As you can see, in Server Network screenshot, there are less number of requests, less data transferred however Finish time, DomContentLoaded time and Load time is almost same to Local Network screenshot. So i'm wondering if it even makes sense to implement bundling and minification in my project.

Any advice?

Comment: Your sample size is very small. But you may want to consider that mobile networks and browsers will handle your website differently and there could be greater time savings. You are probably on an optimal network how might it look on 3g? Browsers can only handle a limited number of requests at a time. So the rest of the requests queue up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes bundling and minification do help in faster loading. In our project we have had a significant performance improvements on the pages where we implemented bundling and minification and where we didn't have. I see that you do not see much difference in the load time but based on my experience yes they do make page load faster. But it could be that you are on a very good network with no load that you don't see much difference.

Comment: makes sense. also i was told, since the server almost matches with the local load performance, it is good since one is being served from local environment which is obviously supposed to be fast while it can't be true about the server.